# How can I fill the right side of an element with another one?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.parent{
  direction: rtl;
  border: 2px solid;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 50%;
}

.full_height{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.full_width1, .full_width2{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="full_height"></div>
  <div class="full_width1">something1</div>
  <div class="full_width2">something2</div>
</div>
```

This is expected output:

[image]

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could look like this:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent{
  direction: rtl;
  border: 2px solid;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.full_height{
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: red;
}
.full_width1, .full_width2{
  min-width: 120px;
  height: 50%;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}
.full_width2{
   background-color: blue;
}
```

You can find a fiddle preview right here: https://jsfiddle.net/7pb8pxnx/2/

Comment: seems good .. thank you ..upvote .. Just one thing, my HTML structure is ok for what I'm trying to do? Or it can be better?

Comment: Structure is fine in my opinion, i prefer dashes rather than underscores for CSS-classes though, for code reviews you can go over to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for CSS naming conventions, I would refer you to this great guideline: http://cssguidelin.es/